Runtime java.lang.AbstractMethodError when name of Flow variaable is changes
I have a Room DAO which returns a Flow<List<>>.  The DAO looks like this:
interface VehicleInfoDao {
    ...

    @get:Query("SELECT vehicleId, modelId, enabled FROM vehicle_info")
    val liveDataVehicleInfo: Flow<List<VehicleIds>>

    ...
}

This runs fine.  However, if I rename the liveDataVehicleInfo to something different, such as liveDataVehicleInf, it builds without complaint but as soon as the program accesses the DAO I get a runtime error.
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.code.appname, PID: 5511
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow com.code.appname.db.VehicleInfoDao.getLiveDataVehicleInf()"
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.example.khughes.machewidget.MainActivity$onCreate$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:128)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher$Worker.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:115)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:103)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:584)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:793)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:697)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:684)
11-17 08:00:40.898  5511  5531 E AndroidRuntime:    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@8734046, Dispatchers.IO]

I've tried cleaning/rebuilding/invalidating caches and none of these fix the problem.  If I change the DAO variable's name back it's fine.  I'm at a complete loss.
FWIW, I'm using Android Studio Koala 2024.1.2 Canary, Gradle 8.7, Gradle Plugin 8.5.2, and these dependencies:
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.7.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.3'

Edit: in case anyone is thinking "why do you need to rename the variable if the code works?", I first came across this problem when I tried to add  a second DAO Flow<List<>> and it returned the same runtime error.
